# MongoDB Compound Indexing + Multiple Indexes + Index Intersection

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, nosql

So, I'm using MongoDB 3.6 to store my data. The collection schema looks like this.

```
{
    enabled: Boolean,
    opening_hours: {
        0: [{
            from: Number,
            until: Number
        }],
        1: [{
            from: Number,
            until: Number
        }],
        ...
        6: [{
            from: Number,
            until: Number
        }],
    },
    opening_exceptions: [{
        from: Date,
        until: Date
    }],
    opening_whitelist: [{
        from: Date,
        until: Date
    }],
    category: String,
    payment_methods: [String]
}
```

My queries look like the following:

```
{
   "enabled":true,
   "$or":[{
        "opening_hours.5": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "from": { "$lte":698 },
                "until": { "$gte":698 }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "opening_whitelist": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "from": { "$lte":new Date(1525444711573) },
                "until": { "$gte":new Date(1525444711573) }
            }
        }
    }],
    "opening_exceptions": {
        "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "from": { "$lte":new Date(1525444711573) },
                "until": { "$gte":new Date(1525444711573) }
            }
        }
    },
    "category": { $in: ["Tecno"] },
    "payment_methods": { $in: ["visa"] }
}
```

The `category` and `payment_methods` fields are sometimes present in the query as well as the `$or` and `opening_exceptions`.

This query needs to run as fast as possible therefore i'm trying to index the collection. I've read most of the MongoDB docs available about indexing (Compound Indexing, Multiple Indexes taking advantage of Index Intersection). However, MongoDB does not support parallel array indexing (for numerous reasons) and even though i've tried to create an index for each combination of the query, Mongo doesn't seem be taking advantage (seeing `cursor.explain()` outputs) of the adequate index.

Any ideas on how to index this collection for getting the best performance on the query?

Maybe adding some metadata to the schema to get it indexable?

Thank you!!

Comment: Is it expected to have multiple values in opening_exceptions array? Or in opening_whitelist array?

Comment: Those arrays will usually be empty or have a small amount of elements